# Matlab Error: Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs

Tags: matlab, printf, cell-array

```
fid = fopen('./tickers.tex', 'wt+');
for x = 1 : size(C.names,1) 
    fprintf(fid, '%s & ', C.names(x,1:end-1)); 
    fprintf(fid, '%s \\\\ \t\n', C.names(x,end)); 
end 
fclose(fid);
```

Why does this give me the error:

Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

While this does work:

```
fprintf(' %f    ', D{:});
```

I'm having difficulties understanding basic matlab datatypes. Could anyone provide me with a solution to print the cell array just like the last syntax?

Comment: `C.names(ind)` gives an element that itself is a "cell"; try `C.names{x,1:end-1}` Reference http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html

Comment: Thanks! Simple question, simple answer ;)

Comment: Yvon please provide your solution as an answer so we can up-vote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from the error and code you have I am assuming C is an array of cells and you want to print some string from each entry of C. Assuming this, your code is incorrect.
Try this:

```
fid = fopen('./tickers.tex', 'wt+');
for x = 1 : size(C,1) 
    fprintf(fid, '%s & ', C{x}.names(1:end-1)); 
    fprintf(fid, '%s \\\\ \t\n', C{x}.names(end)); 
end 
fclose(fid);
```

Is this what you want? If not please provide more information about C