# Matlab Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression

Tags: matlab

I have this code and want to write an array in a tab delimited txt file :

```
fid = fopen('oo.txt', 'wt+');
for x = 1 :length(s)
fprintf(fid, '%s\t\n',  s(x)(1)) ;
end; 
fclose(fid);
```

but I receive this error :

```
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

how should i call  s(x)(1)? s is an array

```
 s <2196017x1 cell>
```

when I use this code I get no error but return me some characters not words.

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\t\n', ( s{x}{1})) ;
```

Comment: Answer is also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190168/matlab-error-function-is-not-defined-for-cell-inputs

Answer (score 1):

With MATLAB, you cannot immediately index into the result of a function using `()` without first assigning it to a temporary variable (Octave *does* allow this though). This is due to some of the ambiguities that happen when you allow this.

```
tmp = s(x);
fprintf(fid, '%s\t\n',  tmp(1)) ;
```

[There are some ways around this but they aren't pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it/3628885#3628885)

It is unclear what exactly your data structure is, but it looks like `s` is  a cell so you should really be using `{}` indexing to access it's contents

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\t\n', s{x});
```

**Update**

If you're trying to read individual words in from your input file and then write those out to a tab-delimited file, I'd probably do something like the following:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
contents = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid)

% Break a string into words and yield a cell array of strings
words = regexp(contents, '\s+', 'split');

% Write these out to a file separated by tabs
fout = fopen('output.tsv', 'w');
fprintf(fout, '%s\t', words{:});
fclose(fout)
```

Comment: tnx a lot but when i did such as your example i get this error `Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.`

Comment: @mary Which one are you using and what *exactly* is `s`?

Comment: s is an array which includes 2196017 words

Comment: @mary Is it a cell array of cell arrays or what?

Comment: s is : s <2196017x1 cell>

Comment: @mary Right but what is *inside* of the cell? Another cell? `disp(size(s)); disp(class(s{1})); disp(size(s{1}))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130302/discussion-between-mary-and-suever).